# Is there a convenient way to add complex numbers in polar form in sympy (python)?

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

I had some trouble adding complex numbers in polar form in sympy.
The following code

```py
from sympy import I, exp, pi, re, im

a = exp(2*pi/3*I)
b = exp(-2*pi/3*I)

c = a+b 
print(c)
print(c.simplify())
print(c.as_real_imag())
print(re(c)+im(c)*I)
print(int(c))
print(complex(c))
```

gives

```
exp(-2*I*pi/3) + exp(2*I*pi/3)
-(-1)**(1/3) + (-1)**(2/3)
(-1, 0)
-1
-1
(-1+6.776263578034403e-21j)
```

What I want, is to get the simplest answer to `a+b`, which is `-1`. I can obtain this, by manually rebuilding `c=a+b` with `re(c)+im(c)*I`. **Why is this necessary? And is there a better way to do this?**

Simply printing `c` retains the polar forms, obfuscating the answer, `c.simplify()` leaves the polar form, but is not really helpful, and `c.as_real_imag()` returns a tuple. `int(c)` does the job, but requires the knowledge, that `c` is real (otherwise it throws an error) and integer (otherwise, this is not the answer I want). `complex(c)` kind of works, but I don't want to leave symbolic calculation. Note, that `float(c)` does not work, since `complex(c)` has a non-zero imaginary part.

Comment: so what type do you want the answer to be? it needs to be consistent depending if the result is pure real, pure imaginary or a combination. `c.as_real_imag()` returns a tuple which is very practical in my opinion, you can easily access the real and imaginary part if needed. You have in your example different return values, depending what are you interested in.

Comment: Maybe `c.rewrite(cos)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9450991/oscar-benjamin has given you the solution. If you are in polar coordinates, your expression may have exponential functions. If you don't want these you have to rewrite into trigonometric functions where special values are known for many values. For example, consider `a`'s `2*pi/3` angle:

```
>>> cos(2*pi/3)
-1/2
>>> sin(2*pi/3)
sqrt(3)/2
```

When you rewrite `a` in terms of `cos` (or `sin`) it becomes the sum of those two values (with `I` on the `sin` value):

```
>>> a.rewrite(cos)
-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2
```

When you rewrite a more complex expression, you will get the whole expression rewritten in that way and any terms that cancel/combine will do so (or might need some simplification):

```
>>> c.rewrite(cos)
-1
```

Comment: I don't think that `rewrite` is a reliable solution. It works in this case because we are adding complex conjugate numbers together and their sum is 100% real. You cannot use it for a decomposition like `z.rewrite(cos) + I*z.rewrite(sin)` because of the lake of independency of the two new expressions